# I am using localization , it doesn't switch between languages , it only returns the default language

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-localization

**middleware**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class localization
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(\Session::has('locale')){
            \App::setLocale(\Session::get('locale'));
        }
       
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**route**

```
Route::get('locale/{locale}', function($locale){
    Session::put('locale',$locale);
    return redirect()->back() ;
});
```

**view**

```
<html lang="{{app()->getLocale()}}">

<a href="locale/en">en</a>
<a href="locale/ar">ar</a>

<h1>@lang('home.title')</h1>


</html>
```

The buttons redirect to the same page without any change. When I change the default language in the file app.php, this changes the language but I need to change it dynamically.